# Chelation and its relation to transition metal ligands

Tags: periodic-table, transition-metals

Can someone explain chelation and its relation to monodentate and tridentate ligands? I dont understand what they mean by chelate effect and chelating rings.

Comment: Would you be willing to provide some more information, for example some specific compounds that seem to be giving you trouble?

Answer (score 2):

I'm giving the answer thinking that you are familiar with ligands and Denticity.

Polydentate ligands form two or more coordinate bond with the central metal atom. For eg:EDTA can form up-to 6 coordinate bond with the central atom. In these situations a single ligand encloses the metal ion like enclosing it in a cage. This is called chelation. Co-ordination compounds with chelated metal ions are more stable then those in which the metal ions are surrounded by many monodentate ligands.If you want more information read the Wikipedia article on this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelation.