# Why are chelate complexes more stable than other complexes with unidentate ligands?

Tags: coordination-compounds

I read that complex compounds with chelating ligands are thermodynamically more stable than complexes without them. Why would that be so?

Comment: also http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31005/whats-so-special-about-chelation