# Which factor drives the stability in chelated complexes?

Tags: coordination-compounds, stability

Which factor drives the stability in chelated complexes?

> Stability, I guess, is supposed to be associated with a release of energy. Does something like this happen in chelated complexes?

Comment: Related: [What's so special about chelation?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/31005/7951)

Comment: @Loong But I have a different query

Comment: Well, your post doesn't point out the difference.

Comment: @Mithoron what about the release in energy?

Comment: You need to edit your post, pointing out how is it exactly and in significant way different.